# Getting url of the following a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I wanted to check the url if it contains subreddit link https://www.reddit.com/r and the name of subreddit coronavirus

```
 import re
 u1='https://www.reddit.com/r/CoronavirusUS/comments/'
 u2='https://www.reddit.com/user/X'
 print(re.findall("(/r\w+)",u1))
```

I have tried several approach but its not working.

How can I solve the issue?

Expected output
check the URL if it contains subreddit and then name of the subreddit

```
u1 is subreddit, u2 is not
subreddit-coronavirus.
```

Comment: Maybe `"/r/(\w+)"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it worked for the name of subreddit, but how to check the URL is subreddit or not, like u2 is not a subreddit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 if 'https://www.reddit.com/r' in link and 'coronavirus' in link.lower():
     print(link, 'is subreddit with coronavirus')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

some_list = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/CoronavirusUS/comments/',
             'https://www.reddit.com/user/X', "some junk", -100]

url = "reddit.com"
path = "/r/coronavirus"

for item in some_list:
    try:
        parsed = urlparse(item)
        if parsed.scheme in ['http', 'https'] and parsed.netloc.endswith(url) and parsed.path.lower().startswith(path):
            print(item)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Which yields

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/CoronavirusUS/comments/
```